# Using three.js in nwjs project

Tags: webpack, three.js, nwjs

We're developing a desktop app using webpack with reactjs and nwjs. In a page of this app a threejs scene is rendered. We use threejs as node module. Everything goes smooth in 'developing mode' (i.e. using `npm run css; webpack-dev-server --env=dev --progress --profile --colors` as commands to launch execution). After building the app (using `nwjs-builder-phoenix`) performance of three scene (actually the building up of the scene) becomes really bad. As an example, to add a multiline of 3000 points in the scene, that in developing mode takes 0.5 secs, in builded app takes 30 secs. To use threejs as js source in minified version, instead of using it as node-module, makes performance bad also in developing mode.

Is there a known issue in using threejs with nwjs/node-webkit that could explain such a situation? And, is there anything that could be done to improve performances in builded app?

We use:

- nwjs 0.25.4
- three 0.86.0
- webpack 2.6.1
- webpack-dev-server 2.4.5

Comment: I'm building an open source game. Created my webpack conf from scratch and experiencing the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?